# Is it normal for students to ask for a lot of reference letters?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I'm currently trying to apply to as many grad schools as I can (France) and all of them require one or more reference letters.

The past few months I feel like I have already bothered me enough with this matter. But unfortunately, some schools requires that the professor sends it personally, instead of having me acting as a middle man.

If I could just get them to write once and send that copy everywhere I would do it but in the current circumstances I cant. And I feel bad for asking more reference letters when their workload is already heavy.

Fortunately, the next deadline is 1 month away.

Comment: "Fortunately, the next deadline is 1 month away." That's not that long

Comment: That's what I told myself until I asked for a reference letter in Early February and got it in mid April

Comment: Doesn't that support my point?

Comment: Yes. I misread it.

Comment: There are sites that support single (or individualised) uploads of references. Some places accept references from such sites. Sorry, I do not have them handy, but they may be googleable.

Answer (score 4):

My solution as a student and my preferred solution as a prof who might get a lot of requests from a student would just be a heads up that a number of requests will be coming in the future months.

That lets the writer know that it is good to keep copies on file, or even prepare a template file for this student so that it takes little time or effort to send out the next letter. Some professors will write a general letter to send everywhere and some will tailor it for a given institution. As the prof, I would probably do a bit of both, depending on whether I had a relationship with the receiving institution and on whether the student is specially qualified for a position.

Don't make every request a surprise with a short deadline. That could be annoying.